# How to write a regular expression in Java to remove all characters in a String after the matching character?

Tags: java, regex

I have something like the below line of String.

```
String log = "Daily batch run has been completed Status = Success at the first attempt Logging out Admin...OK"
String batchOutput = "";
```

I need to extract only "Success at the first attempt".

I have tried out the below.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Status = (.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.match(log);

if (matcher.find()) {

batchOutput = matcher.group(1);
System.out.println(batchOutput) // This displays Status = Success at the first attempt Logging out Admin...OK"
}
```

However, I need to extract out only "Status = Success at the first attempt"

Again I took a substring of the batchOutput string

```
batchOutput = batchOutput.substring(0, batchOutput.indexOf("L")).trim(); // This displays only "Status = Success at the first attempt"
```

I believe that instead of using the substring method, this can be extracted out by using valid regex expression.

Could I get some help on this please?
}

Comment: So, you want to use `"Status = ([^L]*)"`, right? See linked thread, scroll to *a certain single character or a set of characters*

Comment: ^(?:Daily batch run has been completed Status = (Success at the first attempt) Logging out Admin...OK)$. If it matches you will have the string in the first group.